# retaining substring pattern using jquery or plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A textbox has a property of storing a string which has a type telephone number or zip code.

Where and when a user starts typing the keys should fill the textbox in a telephone/zip code format. 
For example -

1st Pattern is 234-23432,

2nd Pattern is (234)24234-324.

So when user types in some keys the characters should be arranged accordingly. Does not matter if the solution  uses plain JavaScript or jQquery

Comment: I'm Sorry I didn't try any solution till now.. Piled up with so many urgent fixes...:( Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [page](http://snipplr.com/view/11578/). you can use following code . you can test it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSkSK/)

```
  $(function() {
    $("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
        var curchr = this.value.length;
        var curval = $(this).val();
        if (curchr == 3) {
            $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
        } else if (curchr == 9) {
            $(this).val(curval + "-");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: So to give more info now. The pattern is saved dynamically by the user. The data will be saved in the pattern like (999)999-999. Where The Parantesis could be substituted with any thing. Or it can be with any separator like just 9999-9999. Where both the data are type - phonenumber. So the function should see for any separator and should also see the number is within the range of the max declared in the pattern. For example if Pattern is (555)999-555.<br> User should be able to enter only number ranging from 0-5 inside () and 0-5 after "-" separator.

Comment: And the above I think can be solved by making a function which creates regular expression by it self and sorts the srting accordingly.

Comment: you can restrict number of character by return false. in function if length exceed.